# How do I use event.preventDefault with KnockoutJs click event handlers?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have the following table row as a script template in KnockoutJs:

```
    <script id="inboxTemplate" type="text/html">           
    <tr data-bind="click: function() { viewInboxModel.selectAction($data); }">                                 
        <td>...</td>                 
        <td>${ CreateDate }</td>               
        <td data-bind="click: function(e){ e.preventDefault();viewInboxModel.clearAction($data); }"><img src="/Content/images/delete.png" height="16px" width="16px"> </td>
    </tr>            
    </script>
```

The problem is when I click the delete button, it is also running the selectAction() method. I've tried using e.preventDefault() in both selectAction click handler and the clearAction() clicker handler to no avail. Is there anyway KnockoutJs can prevent the underlying row from now being clicked if the delete button is clicked?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you have jQuery referenced, then you can safely call `e.stopImmediatePropagation();` in your handler, as it is passed the jQuery event object.  If you are not using jQuery, then you could still do something like:

```
e.cancelBubble = true;
if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/mCxjz/

Comment: In your jsFiddle, the "two" click handler is not properly stopping the event from propagating to the "one" click handler in my current version of Chrome.

Comment: @mkmurray this fiddle references the latest KO from github, but was created before KO 2.0.  In KO 2.0, there was a breaking change to pass the data as the first arg to event handler and the event second.  Fiddle is updated now to use the correct signature.

Comment: In KO 2.1.0 (and maybe other versions...), you can use the clickBubble: false. 
Ex.: <td data-bind="click: myFunction, clickBubble: false"> </td>
See: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html

Answer (score 11):

As per @Benoit Drapeau's comment:

In more recent versions of Knockout you use clickBubble: false. e.g.

```
<td data-bind="click: myFunction, clickBubble: false"> </td>
```

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html