# prevent anchor tag from navigating to home page

Tags: durandal

I have a regular anchor tag with href attribute set to "#". Normally, this prevents from any navigation but in durandal it navigates me to the home view. How can I stop it from navigating to that view?
I can't change the html and stylings. It needs to be that anchor tag. But I can bind a click event to it. Is there any way to cancel navigation in anchor click event?

regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bind a click event to it and call event.preventDefault()

```
<a href="#" id="someAnchor">Example</a>

$(function() {
   $('#someAnchor').click(function(event) { event.preventDefault(); });
});
```

This will prevent the browser from propagating the click event and nothing will happen.  But inside the click event you can do whatever logic you want.

If you are using knockout to bind the click event then please [refer to this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8297335/how-do-i-use-event-preventdefault-with-knockoutjs-click-event-handlers) on how to do it from a knockout binding.

EDIT ** Per Tyrsius' comments its a better practice to use the knockout binding to bind a click event.

So, instead it is recommended you do:

```
<a href="#" data-bind="click: clickHandler">ClickMe</a>

clickhandler = function (e) {
  e.cancelBubble = true;
  if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
};
```

Comment: Since this is posted under the Durandal tag, I think it's safe to assume that knockout at least *should* be used (and that consequentially, jQuery `click` should *not*).

Comment: jQuery is a dependency of Knockout and Durandal so.. I don't see why not. I understand to not create a tight coupling w/ your views from your viewmodel.. but thats if your hardcore mvvm.  Otherwise.. there is always more than one way to skin a cat and its good to know them all.

Comment: If Durandal isn't hardcore mvvm I don't know what is, but there is a practical reason for not doing it this way: the document ready handler doesnt fire after composition, so you can't gaurantee that the `anchor` will exist the register your `click`. It also might be removed and added later (which is *very* likely if it's a SPA). This is just not a good solution.

Comment: Also, jQuery is *not* a dependency of Knockout, only of Durandal. It has some very valid use cases for both, but `click` bindings fall pretty squarely in Knockout's viewmodel jurisdiction (for the reasons above).

Comment: Agree with Tyrsius, Knockout click binding would be a more suitable approach to post as an answer to the question, as is the jQuery approach will probably confuse future readers.

Comment: Your right using the knockout binding would be a better practice. But your previous statement of the anchor not existing isnt entirely true. You can put the code in the viewAttached method of your viewmodel and it will exist at that point.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. Knockout's click binding is the way I waneted it to work. I just didn't know how to cancel that event propagation.

Answer (score 0):

Have all your anchor links start with a prefix. Then have in your `router.guardRoute` function this:

```
if (_.startsWith(instruction.fragment, YOUR_PREFIX))
      return false;
}
```

Worked well for me and no need to add anything else to your app views.

PS. `_.startsWith` is lodash function. If not using lodash do JS string indexOf or whatever